# QGIS Server: Show value in abstract field of published WFS service

Tags: qgis, wfs, metadata, qgis-server, getcapabilities

I published layers from a QGIS project as WFS Service using QGIS Server and everything works fine. Now I want to add a description to each layer, but can't find documentation on how to fill out the `Abstract` field.

I tried to put a value in the Abstract Metadata field, but it doesn't show up in the GetCapabilities service nor in the list of WFS layers when creating a WFS Server Connection.

[image]

Is there a way in QGIS Server to make this information appear?

Comment: Does it show up in DescribeFeatureType for the feature?

Comment: No - but I'm not sure if we are talking about the same issue. I added a screenshot to my question...

Comment: You're right I though you meant abstract featuretype, not layer metadata abstract

Answer (score 0):

You can find this information with a GetProjectSettings request to qgis-server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this work for WFS as well as WMS, I couldn't see any documentation supporting it (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/services/wfs.html).